# Add custom dynamic text box in asp.net zero angular

Tags: asp.net, angular

I am working in asp.net zero with angular, wants to add dynamic text box.

I wants to add custom text box in angular asp.net zero. When i click on button then two text box will be show on screen. If i click again on button then show new two text box on the screen. and i can delete it too.

Any one have idea, how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific feature on asp.net zero, is angular, the best way i can suggest you do it is using angular reactive form. follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3aQl0DCvds) and you will have all the features